# How to select specified data like id in a for loop to use those data in different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-representation

I want to get and store id from idArray to use each id indvidual
I tried to store in session storage but it return the last element

```
success: function (data) {
      const myText = "";
      const addressArray = [];
      const titleArray = [];
      const typeArray = [];
      const idArray = [];
      data.map((user) => {     
        addressArray.push(user.address);
        titleArray.push(user.title);
        typeArray.push(user.jtype);
        idArray.push(user.id);
      });
      container.innerHTML = "";
      for (let i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        let clone = row.cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild(clone);
        container.firstChild.innerHTML = "";
        

        jobtitle.innerHTML = data[i].title;
        jbtype.innerHTML= typeArray[i];
        jbaddress.innerHTML= addressArray[i];

        sessionStorage.setItem('jobid',idArray[i]);
       
        
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue I can see is , since the key is always same , it is overriding the value of the same key.

You can instead do something like

```
sessionStorage.setItem("jobid-"+i,idArray[i]);
```

This should solve the problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the last value because you are using the same key to store each value. Try using a different key for each or alternately, create an array of ids using map function and store the array in session with the key 'jobid'.
You can serialize and store it in session as follows:

`sessionStorage.setItem('jobid', JSON.stringify(idArray));`

To read the same back out you can use code like

`JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('jobid'));`

Comment: i created an arrayfor ids called idArray and i get the data from it

Comment: You can serialize and store it in session as follows:
`sessionStorage.setItem('jobid', JSON.stringify(idArray));`
To read the same back out you can use code like
`JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('jobid'));`

Comment: It works but i want to store one by one because i need the  id to call an api url . i need when i click a button save the id for this element

Comment: Please see the answer below by @Harmandeep. He is appending the id itself to the string 'jobid' to generate new keys each time for each value.